# Распечатать индексы элементов списка

Tags: perl

Есть массив:

```
my @a = qw/qaz wsx edc/;
```

Нужно вывести все элементы с индексами

```
for(@a){
    print $_ "индекс массива"
}

qaz0
wsx1
edc2
```

варианты с `0..$#a` или `scalar @a - 1` не подходят, есть другой способ их распечатать? но с условием что код должен начинаться так: `for(@a){` или `for my $a(@a){`

Comment: а просто завести дополнительную переменную?

Comment: может, специальную? наподобие "$.", "$-[0]" и тд, у перла их много, всех не запомнишь - потому и спрашиваю

Comment: из того, что я знаю, такой переменной нет. Все переменные можно подсмотреть в perlvar

Comment: дополнительную, это так, типа?: my $i = 0;

    for(@a){
    print "$_$i";
    $i++;
    }

Comment: Да, где то так.

Comment: *варианты ... не подходят* -- с чего бы? `say "[$_] $array[$_]" for ( 0 .. $#array )` Или очередное задание странного препода? Ну, тогда `my $i = 0;
for( @array ) { printf "[%u] %s\n", $i++, $_ };` Только зачем такие сложности и наплевательство на принцип KISS - непонятно.

Answer (score 1):

Если при итерации вам нужен индекс/ключ, то нужно испольовать `each`:

```
@x = qw/ 1 2 3 a b c /; 
while( my( $idx, $value ) = each @x ){ 
    print "$idx -- $value\n" 
}

0 -- 1
1 -- 2
2 -- 3
3 -- a
4 -- b
5 -- c
```

Есть также сахар: начиная с `perl-5.18` `each` устанавливает `$_` в текущий индекс/ключ. Поэтому можно писать так:

```
@x = qw/ 1 2 3 a b c /; 
while( each @x ){
    print "$_ -- $x[$_]\n"
}

0 -- 1
1 -- 2
2 -- 3
3 -- a
4 -- b
5 -- c
```

А если просто распечатать индексы нужно, то вот вам ещё 2 варианта:

```
print while each @x; # 012345
print keys @x;       # 012345
```

DOC: [each](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html) и [keys](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html)

---

Если нужно через `for`, то других вариантов нет, кроме как доп. переменной:

```
print 0+$i, " -- $x[$i++]\n"  for @x
```